# Force image dimensions when empty

Tags: html, css

I am creating a grid with images. I have the problem of the empty images:

```css
.myForm {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}

.imgWrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.3333333%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: tomato;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form class="myForm">
    <div class="imgWrapper">
        <img src="http://www.whizzpast.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/vintage-cats-14.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="imgWrapper">
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="imgWrapper">
        <img src="http://www.whizzpast.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/vintage-cats-14.jpg">
    </div>
   
</form>
```

I would like to force the empty images to have the same size as the others. —I don't know if this can be done with flexbox, but I prefer to avoid it—. I think I can do this adding another wrapper, but I would prefer to avoid it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.myForm {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
    display: block;
}

.imgWrapper {
    width: 33%;
    display : inline-block;
    float:left;
     background: tomato;
    min-height : 135px;
    max-height : 135px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form class="myForm">
    <div class="imgWrapper">
      
        <img src="http://www.whizzpast.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/vintage-cats-14.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="imgWrapper">
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="imgWrapper">
        <img src="http://www.whizzpast.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/vintage-cats-14.jpg">
    </div>
   
</form>
```

you just need to add some min-height and min-width and float to your css :

for example :

```
.myForm {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
    display: block;
}

.imgWrapper {
    width: 33%;
    display : inline-block;
    float:left;
     background: tomato;
    min-height : 135px;
    max-height : 135px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Can you please add a snippet?

Comment: yes why not ... i just edited my answer you need to add a little things like float

Comment: Ah, but you are adding another wrapper… I knew this way, but without it, this is another thing…

Comment: here you are i change it to what you wanted now you can use it

Answer (score 0):

You **could** make use of a fixed height for each of the images, and also apply this height to the broken images by targeting the **[attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)** `img[src='']`:

```
img[src=''] {
  height: 217px; /* The height of the actual images in the snippet */
}
```

```css
.myForm {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

.imgWrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3333333%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: tomato;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

img[src=''] {
  height: 217px;
}
```

```html
<form class="myForm">
  <div class="imgWrapper">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1d/58/f1/1d58f1bb767a1bc2231226c4fc9ae85a--film-photography-vintage-photography.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="imgWrapper">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="imgWrapper">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1d/58/f1/1d58f1bb767a1bc2231226c4fc9ae85a--film-photography-vintage-photography.jpg">
  </div>
</form>
```

**However**, in my opinion, it would be much better to simply **hide** broken images entirely, which can be done with:

```
img[src=''] {
  display: none;
}
```

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.myForm {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

.imgWrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3333333%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: tomato;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

img[src=''] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="myForm">
  <div class="imgWrapper">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1d/58/f1/1d58f1bb767a1bc2231226c4fc9ae85a--film-photography-vintage-photography.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="imgWrapper">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="imgWrapper">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1d/58/f1/1d58f1bb767a1bc2231226c4fc9ae85a--film-photography-vintage-photography.jpg">
  </div>
</form>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer doing flexboxes. It's as simple as...

CSS:

```
.myForm {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.imgWrapper {

    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.3333333%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: tomato;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form class="myForm">
    <div class="imgWrapper">
        <img src="http://www.whizzpast.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/vintage-cats-14.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="imgWrapper">
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="imgWrapper">
        <img src="http://www.whizzpast.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/vintage-cats-14.jpg">
    </div>

</form>
```

Example [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/n3jiub0h). I'm assuming you want the empty background image to have a height. Other solutions suggest hiding it entirely, which is an option as well.

Comment: Yep, but as I said, flexbox is forbidden here :)

Comment: ^ You said you'd "*prefer to avoid it*", not that it was forbidden. Flexbox is actually pretty much built for this sort of problem :)